# Sony Xperia Mini Pro have a different behaves differently to the same apk

Tags: android, device

In my application I am creating a journal. In all devices behave correctly, however this device day are to be repeated, appears twice on the same day.

The code is long to be exposed here.

I understand the layout that can be different between devices, but as it is possible that the level of programming may differ between devices?

Comment: Sorry my english, may not have been very explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some trouble with Xperia, I don't know if I'm right, but what I think is that the Xperia I used has Android 2.1 and the rest of the devices, at least have 2.3.

Are your code using webView and images? that was my problem, I solve it adding the images to the /asset folder, but I lost the hdpi, mdpi, ldpi density.

Hope this helps. Regards

Comment: No, I'm not to resort to images ... basically I'm to add rows to a listview, one row for each day. In Experia appear two rows, equal to the same day

Comment: install logcat in the Xperia, and use Log for everything in your code, that was how I found how to solve the mistake. there were some log I wrote, and some nullpointerexception from Xperia